# Does the command FOR XML in MS SQL Server save the file in disk?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Does the command FOR XML in MS SQL Server save the file in disk?

I'm creating a trigger to log operations in a table and part of this trigger is create a XML with the affected row. I'm thinking of using the FOR XML to generate the XML.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_Test 
WHERE ID=3040
FOR XML RAW
```

My worry is that I will be using it in a trigger and I don´t want to save files in the server every time I call the FOR XML function.

In addition: would you guys know how to parse it to varchar?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any `SELECT` query, a query with the `FOR XML` clause will return the result to the client and not save the result to disk.

You can use a scalar subquery to assign the result XML to a varchar variable instead of returning to the client:

```
DECLARE @xml varchar(MAX) =
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.TBL_Test 
        WHERE ID=3040
        FOR XML RAW
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! Your answer saved me from a headache!